# How can I change the default location of where Python writes/opens CSV files from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> How can I change the default location of where Python writes/opens files from?

I recently downloaded IPython and have noticed that any time a text file is written or a CSV file is needed to import data for pandas/numpy manipulation the files MUST be in MyDocuments.  I'd like to create a particular folder in another file that it automatically writes/opens files from.

Is there  a way to do this?

Comment: Just specify files with theirfull path.  You can change the current directory, but there isn't any advantage to doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the current directory that IPython is running in through the `os` module.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Oliver/Documents/Project Name/data')
```

If you want to change the startup directory when clicking on the IPython icon form the Start Menu, you do so by the "Start in:" directory in the shortcut.

1. Right click on the IPython icon
2. Go to the Shortcut tab
3. Change the "Start in:" location

[image]

Comment: So this seems to just change the directory after that code is initialized, but when I close out and reopen IPython it returns the directory to MyDocuments.  Is there a way to change the default directory so that I don't have to start every code with that?

Comment: I am guessing you are using an IPython shortcut.  I have added to my answer for that case.